# Set active caret at DOM#id (after, before the specified div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, caret

I need to set the caret position after DOM element with #id in contenteditable div. In such way that I will be able to continue typing text.

General problem is

1. get the caret position of specified DOM element (ie. span or div with #id)
2. set the caret at this position (ie. after this DOM element + be able to write text becouse of focus)

---

example html structure:

```
<div id="container" contenteditable="true">
    dasidjsaid<div id="el1">sdsad</div>fdfhsdhdsf<div id="el2">sdsad</div>afasf
    <div id="el3">test</div><div id="el4">jsj</div> <div id="el5">32</div>sadsa
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to move the caret to the end of the div (so the caret is between sdsad and </div>)

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 rather **after** or **before** div with specific id. For example after #el3: `...<div id="el3">test</div>CARET<div id="el4">...`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```js
function setToStart(element) {
  if(!element) {
    return;
  }
  
  element.focus();
  
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(element, 0);
  range.setEnd(element, 0);
  range.collapse(true);

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();

  try {
    sel.addRange(range);
  } catch (e) { }
}

function setToEnd(element) {
  
    element.focus();

    var nodeStack = [element];
    var node = null;
    var lastNode = element;
    var charIndex = 0;

    while ((node = nodeStack.pop())) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            lastNode = node;
            charIndex = node.length;
        } else {
            var i = node.childNodes.length;
            while (i--) {
                nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(lastNode, charIndex);
    range.setEnd(lastNode, charIndex);
    range.collapse(true);

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();

    try {
        sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) { }
}


document.getElementById('setStart').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setToStart(document.getElementById('first'));
});
document.getElementById('setEnd').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setToEnd(document.getElementById('first'));
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><h1>Title</h1><p id="first">Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p><p id="second">Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p></div>

<button id="setStart">Set to START of first paragraph</button>
<button id="setEnd">Set to END of first paragraph</button>
```

Comment: @ziom This does work in Safari/Chrome - I'll take a look to see if I can figure out the issue with Firefox.